# Pathfinding algorithm for big amount of graphs

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

There's a small program like Simulink - let's see some abstract blocks connectes by nets. I have to develop an algorithm that makes these nets get around obstacles (that is, other lines and blocks).

I tried to use some pathfinding algorithms like Lee algorithm or A* algorithm, but they seemed too slow for big amount of graphs (width of window * height of window).

Could you please tell me which algorithm would be the best for this case? Maybe is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: I do not get the meaning of your first sentence. Simulink is everything but no "small program". Did you maybe want to include external links?... If you have code, share it and we can hopefully help you optimize it. If you created a Simulink model you can at least share a picture of your block diagram... But whatever you do, DO NOT POST CODE AS PICTURE!!...

Comment: @SvenKrüger We do own small program with C++ that have simplified functionality of Simulink.

Comment: So the problem does occurr within your software in the case of an "auto routing" function?

Comment: @SvenKrüger Yup. My software is just a demo version of program with usual empty rectangles and lines for testing algorithm.

Comment: Yet again. We can better help you, when you share some source code.